# Path variable in servlet url for Spring web mvc

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm wondering is it possible to have path variable in `server.servlet-path` with DispatcherServlet? I know of course it possible in controller, but I'd like to have it in one place instead of updating 70 endpoints.

Like:

```
server.servlet-path=/{client-name}/api/v4
```

And for example that `client-name` will be available in request attributes, headers, etc.

Or I need to implement my own dispatcher which will do that logic?

Comment: No it isn't possible as the servlet path has to be static.

Comment: Ok, assume we have static path '/'.

Comment: And then what? You cannot put placeholders (unless resolved at startup time) in that parameter. So it won't work. Also if it is for all controllers you might want to use URL rewriting to strip the `client-name` part and make it an attribute in your request (or as a header).